# Internal file transfers to a Windows-7 computer has pauses of 20s

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, home-networking, file-transfer

This happens both with file explorer copying and with Robocopy when copying large files from a Windows 10 machine to a Windows 7 machine.

The file will start copying, then pause for about 20 seconds, then resume, then pause again...  The length of the pauses is suspiciously consistent.

What can be causing it?

**Edit #1:**

I tried copying to a different computer on the network and saw no such pauses.  Copying with robocopy to a wired connection (Windows 8.1) was fast with no pauses, while copying to a wireless one (Windows 10, 802.2n) was slower with short stutters (a second or so).  So it must be the target computer.

Some more information:
The target computer is a Windows 7 machine connected to a WRT54G acting as a bridge, which is connected to my "main" router over coaxial wiring via a pair of [Actiontec ECB6200 MoCA adapters](https://actiontecsupport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/categories/115000073443-ECB6200-Bonded-MoCA-2-0-Network-Adapter).  IPv6 is disabled.

Some sites recommend disabling "Large Send Offload (LSO)" on the network adapter, but when I tried it, the machine lost all connectivity.

**Edit #2:**

The Windows 7 machine downloads from the Internet at close to the maximum speed of my external connection (75Mb/s), only transfers to it from other machines on the internal network exhibit the problem.

Comment: Slow buffering on one end or the other will do that. If it's a big file, not a series of small files, it's very common. You can change the MTU values on both computers in the Advanced section of your network adapters properties, and set a metrics manually, at 576 instead of the default 1500. This *could* speed things up.

Comment: @Didier, the duration of the pauses (20s) seems too long for buffering

Comment: Not sure, but like I said, it depends on the type and size of the files you are trying to copy. I read the edits in your question, and if you're on a WiFi network, then it definitely could be buffering, due to loss of packets, maybe. Have you tried to change the metrics in your connection?

Answer (score 0):

After finding an updated network card driver, I could disable all the "offload" settings without losing connectivity.  This solved the problem.